# How to create a pie chart for yes and no answers in Spotfire and not display the Percentage of Yes/No?

Tags: pie-chart, spotfire

I am trying to create a Pie chart as markers in Spotfire map to Show Yes/No answers. How do I do to  Display yes and No in pie Sector's instead of Percentage? I am attaching an Excel Spreadsheet with Data with this.

I am expecting to get individual Pie chart for each well in the Spotfire map. For example for WELL_1 Data, the pie chart should have two sectors of two different colors one for YES and one for NO and Sector 1 Should show PRODUCTION, COMPLETION Labels(for yes Category) inside the sector and the Other sector Should show PVT, Image Lables (for no category).

I have tried using the Pie marker option in Spotfire Settings, but not getting the result I am expecting. Any help would be appreciated.

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zxgU.png).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vulbe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while Spotfire excels at reading data up and down columns, it's not really designed to read left to right across rows.

you will need to unpivot your table to be tall-and-skinny instead of short-and-wide.

I recommend to start by adding a linked copy of your data table. this way your original table isn't changed, so any visualizations you've already built won't break.

since you haven't specified your Spotfire version, I'll assume you're using 10.x, and my screenshots will reflect that. I'll also be calling your original table `Data Table`, because I'm lazy and didn't change it in my screenshots ;)

1. click the + icon in the top left corner
2. click `Other`
3. under "Linked copy to data table in analysis", choose your `Data Table`
4. rename the new table to `Data Table unpivot` to distinguish it, then click OK
5. from the **Data** menu, click **Transform data...**
6. select Unpivot from the dropdown, then click Insert
7. configure the transformation [image: like so]
8. click OK until you get back to the canvas
9. from the **Data** menu, click **Add calculated column**
10. enter an expression like the following

`CASE 
      WHEN [Category] in ("PRODUCTION", "COMPLETION") THEN "Sector 1"
      WHEN [Category] in ("PVT", "IMAGE") THEN "Other"
    END`

11. call this column something like **Sector**

now that you've got the data configured, you can set up the pie chart as needed. here's a sample of that which I put together quickly. I set up the pies on a trellis to illustrate how it might look in your map.

[image: final result]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for except instead of showing the percentage value inside the sector, how do I show the Name of the category inside the sector. I tried playing with different options available in Spotfire but still couldn't get it. This is the image I am exactly trying to replicate in Spotfire. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I have added the image in my first post for reference.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to achieve what is in your sketch. you're trying to simultaneously divide the pie by yes/no **and** by category. it doesn't really work this way. what you might try instead is to use a Table or Cross Table details visualization so that when you select one or more pies, you can see the category breakdown. to do this, right click your chart and then select "Create Details Visualization...". for more info on this works, look into the Marking feature in the documentation.